# about compilation error in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include

Error   1   error C2039: 'memchr' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstring 19  new project 17

Comment: Are you sure about the tags: "python", "C#" and "ruby"?

Comment: I've retagged it for you to something hopefully more helpful :)

Comment: weird, this is an error in a system header. Sounds like a wrong project config.

Answer (score 2):

You included  header. This declares memchr function in std namespace. So you either include string.h or memory.h headers instead of cstring, or use std namespace when calling memchr.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an `#include` directive inside of a `namespace` somewhere.